# Scrapy spider finishing early for no apparent reason

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider (code at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/da1b487b2d7790b6f954)) which seems to run fine, apart from the fact that it suddenly stops for no apparent reason. When it stops, the last bit of the log file is:

```
2012-12-28 23:42:04+0000 [church] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.achurchnearyou.com/cogges-st-mary/> (referer: http://www.achurchnearyou.com/clifton-reynes-st-mary-the-virgin/)
2012-12-28 23:42:04+0000 [church] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.achurchnearyou.com/cogges-st-mary/>
    {'archdeaconry': u'OXFORD',
     'archdeaconry_id': u'271',
     'benefice': u'Cogges and S Leigh',
     'benefice_id': u'27',
     'deanery': u'WITNEY',
     'deanery_id': u'27109',
     'legal_name': u'Cogges',
     'parish_id': u'270245'}
2012-12-28 23:42:04+0000 [church] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.achurchnearyou.com//> from <GET http://www.achurchnearyou.com/venue.php?V=0083>
2012-12-28 23:42:04+0000 [church] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Is there any reason that a spider might decide it is finished straight after redirecting a URL? The interesting thing is that I have some custom DownloaderMiddleware which will catch a redirect like this and create a new request instead (basically some URLs that I'm trying will redirect to the homepage, and I want to ignore those and create a different URL instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..

Looked at your code (seems clean) but I think the error is simpler (still do not know why you started with the initial id = 63..)

But reverse engineering your task. the simples answer is:

1. The 'parish' that has the id 83 does not exist or has an error.

if you go to http://www.achurchnearyou.com/send_message.php?venue_id=82 it works.
but if try http://www.achurchnearyou.com/send_message.php?venue_id=83

(note the id 82 vs 83)

the NAME of the parish 'disappear' the same if other functions.

The reason you are getting your redirect is because, instead of showing a 404 file not found, the CMS/Website is redirecting you to the home page.